# How to convert time to UTC before sending to server in Ruby on Rails application using jQuery Datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, haml, jquery-ui-datepicker

I recently took over a fully functioning project written in Ruby on Rails.  A bug was reported for which I am trying to solve and not having much success.

This is the CoffeeScript code that is called in the Haml code:

```coffee
$('#report-datetime-picker').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker12Hour: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 5,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'
  }, (start, end) ->
    # assign human readable string to input box
    # unix times are the real values sent to server.  datetime-text-field is just user frontend
    $('#datetime-start').val(start.unix())
    $('#datetime-end').val(end.unix())
    $('#datetime-text-field').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') + " - " + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
  )
```

and:

```
                %label#datetime-label{ for: 'datetime-text-field' } Date/Time Range
                .form-group
                    .input-group.date#report-datetime-picker
                        %span.input-group-addon.add-on
                            %i.fa.fa-calendar

                        %input.form-control#datetime-text-field{ type: 'text', value: @time_format }

                %input#datetime-start{ hidden: true, name: 'startTime', text: 'text', value: (@start_time.to_i rescue nil) }
                %input#datetime-end{ hidden: true, name: 'endTime', text: 'text', value: (@end_time.to_i rescue nil) }

                %button.btn{ type: 'submit' } Submit
```

The issue is that when a user selects a date range, it is being converted to its UTC equivalent with regards to the user's current system time.

For example, if a user in the Eastern timezone wants to pull a monthly report and thus selects "4/1/2020 0:00 - 4/30/2020 23:59", it is instead sending to the server `4/1/2020 04:00 - 5/1/2020 03:59`, causing the monthly report to miss the first four hours of activity, and incorrectly including the first four hours of the following month's activity.  Month relations are not able to be used, as the time ranges are not necessarily a monthly report even though that is the most common use-case.

I checked application.rb and `config.time_zone = 'UTC'`.  I also scoured the rest of the code and all timezone references are in UTC.

I also confirmed that if a user in the Eastern timezone selects "4/1/2020 00:00" in the date picker, the time that is actually stored in the start time is `4/1/2020 04:00`, not `4/1/2020 00:00`.

Comment: Hi Tim and welcome to SO. This behaviour seems correct to me. I assume that if someone in the Eastern Timezone saves  a document at midnight, this too would be saved as `04:00`, and therefore the query seems correct to me. The rule of thumb should be to save everything serverside as UTC, and only convert on display / user entry to / from the users timezone.

Comment: For saving records, yes, midnight local time would be 04:00 server time (and thus technically the next month).  however for pulling reports it is causing confusion and incorrect data.  When someone wants to pull data for the month of April, for example, they want 4/1/2020 00:00 - 4/30/2020 23:59, not 4/1/2020 04:00 - 5/1/2020 03:59.  Long story short, when they pull reports for the "current month", it may only show a total of 50 transactions instead of 75 transactions if 25 happened between 00:00-03:59 server time in the new month.

Comment: To be clear, the issue is not with the query itself - that is returning correctly from what is passed to the server.  The issue is that the jQuery datepicker is converting the time from local to UTC prior to sending the request to the server, thereby requesting the incorrect date/time range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the query works fine but is displaying it incorrectly,try converting to a normal JS date object rather than the `.unix()` method, then convert to UTC on the server

```
$('#datetime-start').val(start.toDate())
$('#datetime-end').val(end.toDate())
```

When the form is submitted, and the values are sent to the server, they should contain the timezone info (eg. `Wednesday, April 8, 2020 11:11:50 AM GMT+01:00 DST`)

If you parse this into a date object server side you can then convert it to a `Time` object with `Time.parse` and use `.utc()` to convert it from the given timezone to UTC.